# Swift: Downcast causes application to crash, why?

Tags: ios, cordova, swift

I have following snippets of code where I have crash on some devices:

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000cbd
```

Code:

```
var obj:AnyObject = command.arguments[0] as AnyObject!
var theData:AnyObject = obj["getContactImagesByEmails"] as AnyObject!

if let contactImagesByEmails:AnyObject = obj["emails"]{
   if contactImagesByEmails is Array<String>{
 /*line 176*/  let array:Array<String> = 
                  contactImagesByEmails as Array<String> // CRASH happens here

       results = WmSqliteImagesModel.getInstance.getImagesByEmailAsWmContactImage(array) as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
            }
        }
```

---

*Full stack trace*

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x0000000100559794 swift_unknownRetain + 32
1  MyApp                       0x000000010017c8a0 MyApp.Plugin.(getContactImagesByEmails (MyApp.Plugin) -> (ObjectiveC.CDVInvokedUrlCommand) -> ()).(closure #1) (Plugin.swift:176)
2  MyApp                       0x000000010017c8a0 MyApp.Plugin.(getContactImagesByEmails (MyApp.Plugin) -> (ObjectiveC.CDVInvokedUrlCommand) -> ()).(closure #1) (Plugin.swift:176)
3  MyApp                       0x00000001001790b0 partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned () -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in ()) -> (@out ()) with unmangled suffix "125" (Plugin.swift:62)
4  MyApp                       0x0000000100179120 partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@in ()) -> (@out ()) to @callee_owned () -> (@unowned ()) with unmangled suffix "128" (Plugin.swift:62)
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001937e13ac _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001937e136c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001937ed40c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1152
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001937ee75c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001939bd2e4 _pthread_wqthread + 816
```

The `Plugin.swift:176` points to:

```
let array:Array<String> = contactImagesByEmails as Array<String>
```

Do I miss something? I think this code should be safe.

if `contactImagesByEmails is Array<String>` returns `true`, why `contactImagesByEmails as Array<String>` fails?

Please help,

**[EDIT]**

`command` has type of `CDVInvokedUrlCommand`

```
@interface CDVInvokedUrlCommand : NSObject {
    NSString* _callbackId;
    NSString* _className;
    NSString* _methodName;
    NSArray* _arguments;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `var obj:AnyObject = command.arguments[0] as AnyObject!` to do? I can see how it compiles, but I can't imagine how it does anything useful. Casting to `AnyObject!` is a very strange downcast.

Comment: @RobNapier `obj["getContactImagesByEmails"]` returns Optional so I unwrap it and promise that `theData` is not `nil` otherwise it will crash before. How do I need to write this?

Comment: What type do you actually expect `command.arguments[0]` to be? Do you expect it to be a Dictionary? Is it a Dictionary? What type is `command?`

Comment: `command.arguments[0]` in my case return `AnyObject` that might be Dictionary or String or Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this can actually fixes the problem, but there's a bit of redundancy in the 2 `if`s and the following `let`. It can simply be written as:

```
if let contactImagesByEmails = obj["emails"] as? Array<String> {
    results = WmSqliteImagesModel.getInstance.getImagesByEmailAsWmContactImage(contactImagesByEmails) as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
}
```

Moreover, it would be safer to combine optional binding and optional downcast when invoking `getImagesByEmailAsWmContactImage`

```
if let results = WmSqliteImagesModel.getInstance.getImagesByEmailAsWmContactImage(contactImagesByEmails) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
    ...
}
```

Last, are you sure `getInstance` is a property and not a method? Shouldn't it be:

```
if let results = WmSqliteImagesModel.getInstance().getImagesByEmailAsWmContactImage(contactImagesByEmails) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `getInstance` is a Singelton instance: `class var getInstance :WmSqliteImagesModel {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = WmSqliteImagesModel()
        }
        
        return Singleton.instance
    }`

Comment: A verb in a name usually indicates it does something, i.e. it's a method - I would rename it to `instance` for clarity - but that's just a stylistic thing

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try an alternate approach to getting the casted value:

```
if let contactImagesByEmails = obj["emails"] as? [String] {
       results = WmSqliteImagesModel.getInstance.getImagesByEmailAsWmContactImage(contactImagesByEmails) as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
    }
```

I also wonder if your crash is not from naming your variable "array" in your original code...

Answer (score 1):

Simplify this step by step with fewer references to `AnyObject` (and certainly not `AnyObject!`). The compiler is probably letting through something that is illegal, because when you start pulling out `AnyObject` you're saying "I know exactly what I'm doing; don't check this."

You'd expect this code to be something like:

```
let obj = command.arguments[0]
if let contactImagesByEmails = obj["emails"] as? [String] {
    results = WmSqliteImagesModel.getInstance.getImagesByEmailAsWmContactImage(array) as? [String: AnyObject]
}
```

In the end `results` would be a `[String:AnyObject]?`

The key point here is that you should get rid of as many references to `AnyObject` as you can, and you should use `if-let-as?` to determine if the types are what you expect.

The fact that `command.arguments` is filled with things of various types that you have to type-check is pretty dangerous and a sign of a serious design problem. If there really are several types in there, you should use an enum rather than type-checking against random things like `[String:AnyObject]`. That's what enums are explicitly for. (If this is bridging from ObjC; enums may not be possible here, but even in ObjC, the right answer is seldom to have an `NSArray` filled with heterogeneous types. You create a class there to hold them rather than an enum.)

Comment: thank you for detailed description. I'll try this approach and will accept. In cordova I get object (command) from Javascript (no-type-variable)